# How do I find number of subsets satisfying two constraints?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> **Moderator Note:** This is also posted on StackOverflow as [How do I find number of subsets satisfying two constraints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51222488/how-do-i-find-number-of-subsets-satisfying-two-constraints).

Suppose I have a set $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and I have to find a number of subsets that have $k$ number of elements and must have an element $p$, Let's assume $k=3$ and $p=2$, So I need number of subsets of size $3$ must be having element $2$ in it, In this case there will be $3$ Subsets.

How can I calculate it using formulas?

Comment: If the set $A$ has $n$ elements, then the set $A'=A-\{p\}$ (so $A'$ is the set $A$ with the element $p$ removed from it) has $n-1$ elements.  You just need to choose $k-1$ elements from $A'$.

Comment: Got it...thanks....

Comment: @lulu It seems like your comment should be an answer.